# c# - view to controller - Value changes on button click and Enter press

Tags: c#, html, forms, razor

I have the below cshtml form which sends the collections value into Controller while clicking the button. This functionality is working fine when the user clicks the button.

```
<form class="search search--large col--large-8" action="/search.asp" method="get" data-component="search">
            <div class="search__wrapper">
                <input id="landing-header-search" class="search__input" type="text" name="searchterm" value="" placeholder="Search Forum Disucssion" data-modal-focus data-search-input autocomplete="off" />
                <input type="hidden" name="collections" value="forumdiscussion" />
                <button class="search__submit button ui-kit-button-medium" type="submit">
                    <span class="button__text">Search</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The above form send the button to below code.

When I Press through mouse click on submit button the collections parameter is of value "forumdiscussion" but when i press Enter Key the collections parameter is "Null". I want the collections parameter to be same on both occasions.

```
 [QsParams("searchterm", "collections", "searchcoll", "page")]
        public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm, string[] collections, string searchcoll, PagerParameters pagerParameters) {
            _metaService.SetMeta("robots", "noindex,nofollow");

            searchcoll = searchcoll ?? "All";

            // create breadcrumb shape
            var breadcrumbShape = _orchardServices.New.Parts_Breadcrumbs(
                Breadcrumbs: _breadcrumbsService.GetBreadcrumbLinks("Home [] > Search []")
            );

            // create search box shape
            var searchBoxShape = _orchardServices.New.Parts_Search_Box(
                IsSearchPage: true,
                Query: searchTerm,
                SearchCollections: collections ?? new[] { searchcoll }
            );
}
```

But the functionality is not working fine when pressing the Enter Key. We are sending the collections value into another method for processing.

Comment: Try changing button to input.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Thanks for your input i changed the button as you suggested and it worked. Can you explain why it worked just i can understand better.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Also The textbox provides autocomplete suggested result. While clicking the autocomplete suggestion this issue occurs. Any idea on handling that.